# How to debug and correct sizing problems connected with amsfonts?

Tags: nath, amsfonts

Depending on whether `amsfonts` is included, rendering is different and undesirable when it is included.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{nath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        (\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 &  1\end{matrix})
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        (\begin{matrix}a & b \\ c &  d\end{matrix})
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

What one should look for is how matrix contents is aligned with respect to surrounding parenthesis.

Comment: `nath` output is wrong in the first place.

Comment: @egreg @tohecz I suspected that `nath` is what's wrong. So I wish to correct it...

Comment: @tohecz `{lmodern}` seems to be enough :-) Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say how exactly this causes a problem, but obviously `amsfonts` change some properties of the default Computer Modern fonts. Loading Latin Modern solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{nath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        (\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 &  1\end{matrix})
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        (\begin{matrix}a & b \\ c &  d\end{matrix})
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution is good for `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` but not for `\documentclass[10pt]{article}`...

Comment: Seems to be my bad, it's independent of `amsfonts` now.

Comment: What should I do if I need Cyrillic fonts (`\textit` ones, more specifically)?

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov I think that adding `T2A` to `[T1,T2A]{fontenc}` should do the job somehow, but I'm not sure, sorry...